# Google Kubernetes Engine(GKE) pod unable to release the liquibase lock even after updating the databasechangeloglock

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, liquibase

I have a pod which worked fine in dev environment in GKE. Unfortunately, I have deployed changes while the pod is running and now the newly created pod unable to acquire the lock. It is raising the following error.

```
Could not acquire change log lock. Currently locked by main-78ddd4b475-t8c68
```

But the pod name which is showing in the error is already been deleted. So, I have followed some Stack Overflow answers and updated the dbchangeloglock file with

```
update DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK set locked=0, lockgranted=null, lockedby=null where id=1;
```

It did not work and then I even deleted the logs from the databasechangelog and then restarted the pods but still I am facing the same error.

Comment: Could you share your yaml deployment files so it will be possible to [reproduce your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? How exactly did you deployed the changes which caused new pod is unable to acquire the lock?

Comment: @MikolajS. We have two environments in GKE. In one environment, I have pushed the code to BitBucket which started pipeline and my pod is updated. Then, in few minutes I had to do some changes and push the code to BitBucket which made old pod to get deleted and started the new pod but my new pod is showing error that, "Could not acquire the lock as it is acquired by xyz(old pod name) ".